# Share Session Between Ionic3 App and Joomla

Tags: php, angular, session, ionic-framework, joomla

I have Ionic3 App and Joomla Backend (api.php width all required functions)

I am using `Http`, and `Storage` modules to connect api.php, I have Successful requests (user/login, user/profile etc..) but every time I am making new request, session in my api.php It is generated again..... but same requests from postman not generates new session, why?

**For example:**

If I will log-in from app , session in my joomla backend is **right**, but if I will use other request in my **app** then **session** will generated **again** (**should not**) but width other data (no more user_id and other identifers in session)

but same requests from **postman**, will only generate **one** session.

Comment: Have you set `withCredentials: true` in the `let options = new RequestOptions` of your `Http` ?

Comment: in my login function? or all function I have?

Comment: in my header I have only: this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

Comment: if you are using cookie session, you have to set it in each http request

Comment: can you give me one example? one of my requests is:   //get user chat list 
  public getMyChatList(token){
    return this.http.post(this.sharedVars.getApi(),"action=messages/getMyChatList&token="+token, this.options
    ).map(res => res.json());
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
```

then

```
http.get(url, options)
```

or for post

```
let body = JSON.stringify({key: someValue}); // data you want to send to the backend
// let body = JSON.stringify(jsonData); // data you want to send to the backend
http.post(url, body, options)
```

if you are usign `HttpClient`

```
http.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
```

Comment: this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });

Comment: also I have included import { Http ,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

Comment: OK I dont know which version of Angular you are using, maybe is the latest so try just `http.get(url, { headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true })`

Comment: when you are using `http.post` take in mind that the second parameter is th e `body` or data you send to the server and the third is the `RequestOptions`. In your code, you're setting `RequestOptions` in the place of `body`. [link More Info](https://angular.io/api/http/Http)

Comment: sorry I am new in typescript I will be glad if you show me how I must configure right to solve session problem. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer. There you can see how you should structure the `http.post` that is what I can help you